# What wrong when SimpleXMLRPC and DBusGMainLoop working in the same time

Tags: python, voip, xml-rpc, sip, dbus

In python I try create a service that maintain calling event between SflPhone(dbus service) and external app, when I start SimpleXMLRPCServer my service no longer response for any calling event, such as on_call_state_changed function was not called.

When I comment out **`thread.start_new_thread(start_server(s,))`**  everything is work well. I don't know how to make this two thing work together. Does one can help?
Thank.

```
import dbus
from dbus.mainloop.glib import DBusGMainLoop
import gobject
from gobject import GObject
from SimpleXMLRPCServer import SimpleXMLRPCServer
import thread
from os import path

class SlfPhoneConnector :

    def __init__(self) :

        self.activeCalls = {}

        account = {
            "username" : "1111", 
            "Account.type" : "SIP", 
            "hostname" : "192.168.1.109", 
            "Account.alias" : "1111", 
            "password":"1111", 
            "Account.enable" : "TRUE"
        }

        session = dbus.SessionBus()

        conf_obj = session.get_object("org.sflphone.SFLphone", "/org/sflphone/SFLphone/ConfigurationManager")  
        self.conf_mgr = dbus.Interface(conf_obj ,"org.sflphone.SFLphone.ConfigurationManager")

        call_obj = session.get_object("org.sflphone.SFLphone", "/org/sflphone/SFLphone/CallManager")  
        self.call_mgr = dbus.Interface(call_obj ,"org.sflphone.SFLphone.CallManager")


        self.call_mgr.connect_to_signal('incomingCall', self.on_incoming_call)
        self.call_mgr.connect_to_signal('callStateChanged', self.on_call_state_changed)

        self.account_id = self.conf_mgr.addAccount(account)

        self.conf_mgr.sendRegister(self.account_id, 1)           

        #self.call_mgr.placeCall(self.account_id, self.account_id, "2222" )  

    def on_incoming_call(self, account, callid, to):
        print "Incoming call: " + account + ", " + callid + ", " + to
        self.activeCalls[callid] = {'Account': account, 'To': to, 'State': '' }   

        self.call_mgr.accept(callid)

    # On call state changed event, set the values for new calls, 
    # or delete the call from the list of active calls
    def on_call_state_changed(self, callid, state):
        print "Call state changed: " + callid + ", " + state
        if state == "HUNGUP":
            try:
                del self.activeCalls[callid]
            except KeyError:
                print "Call " + callid + " didn't exist. Cannot delete."

        elif state in [ "RINGING", "CURRENT", "INCOMING", "HOLD" ]:
            try:
                self.activeCalls[callid]['State'] = state 
            except KeyError, e:
                print "This call didn't exist!: " + callid + ". Adding it to the list."
                callDetails = self.getCallDetails(callid)
                self.activeCalls[callid] = {'Account': callDetails['ACCOUNTID'], 'To': callDetails['PEER_NUMBER'], 'State': state }
        elif state in [ "BUSY", "FAILURE" ]:
            try:
                del self.activeCalls[callid]
            except KeyError, e:
                print "This call didn't exist!: " + callid   


    def getCallDetails(self, callid):
        """Return informations on this call if exists"""
        return self.call_mgr.getCallDetails(callid)

    def place_call(self, callid):
        self.call_mgr.placeCall(self.account_id, self.account_id, callid)

    def hangup(self) :
        call0 = self.activeCalls.keys()[0]
        self.call_mgr.hangUp(call0)


def start_server(obj):
    server = SimpleXMLRPCServer( ("localhost", 9988), allow_none= True)
    server.register_instance(obj)

    print "server start @localhost 9988 forever ..."
    server.serve_forever()

if __name__ == "__main__" :

    DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)
    s  = SlfPhoneConnector()

    thread.start_new_thread(start_server(s,))

    ... {{ another code here }}

    #loop = gobject.MainLoop()
    #loop.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding after ifmain trick:

```
gobject.threads_init()
dbus.glib.init_threads()
```